# Ansible idempotency issue with unarchive and then modify extracted file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In one of the ansible roles we extract some tar.gz file and then we replace one of the extracted files with another one to fix some issue.

The problem is when we run ansible again, ansible is extracting the archive back again since the directory content is changed and naturally marking the task changed and also replaces the file again as expected.

So we have two "changes" now everytime we run the playbook...

How should I handle this issue to keep the operation idempotent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `exclude` option to ignore certain paths, see [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html).
i.e.

```
- unarchive:
    src: https://example.com/example.zip
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    remote_src: True
    exclude: bad.config
```

`creates` might also suit you, unarchive step will not be run if specified path already exists on remote machine

Comment: oh I looked for exclude option in the docs but missed somehow... Anyways, exclude didn't work probably some bug or smt. Fixed it with `creates`, which makes more sense for my case... thanks...